# Formating string from List<T>

Tags: c#, string, format

I have a class with List

```
public class PolynomialCoefficients<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> coefficients;

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        StringBuilder polynomialString = new StringBuilder();
        char separator = ':';

        foreach(T coefficient in coefficients)
        {
            polynomialString.Append(String.Format("0.0000", coefficient.ToString()));
            polynomialString.Append(separator);
        }

        polynomialString.Remove(polynomialString.Length - 1, 1); 
        return polynomialString.ToString();
    }
}
```

Lets say that list contains elements: 1,2,3
I want to call
    ToString("0.000")
and get output: 1.000:2.000:3.000
but every time output is similar to 0.000:0.000:0.000

Answer (score 5):

String.Format needs a very specific kind of string. You gave it a literal string to print:

```
String.Format("0.0000", coefficient.ToString());
```

So it just printed it. If you had given it a *placeholder*:

```
String.Format("{0}", coefficient.ToString("0.0000"));
```

It would have substituted the passed argument in. You can also specify the format of the placeholder:

```
String.Format("{0:f4}", coefficient);
```

"f4" would give you your format. The standard formatting strings can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't need a `ToString()` call on the `coefficient.ToString()`. Second, your format string is a bit incorrect: you need to use the `"{0:0.0000}"` form.

And while we're at it, your code can be greatly simplified:

```
var result = string.Join(";", coefficients.Select(c => string.Format("{0:0.0000}", c));
return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because of call to `ToString` in `String.Format` and not specifying the [place holder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
String.Format("0.0000", coefficient.ToString())
                                  //^^^^^
```

`String.Format` with your format should expect a floating point number, it will not work on string values, for `string` values, format would be ignored and passed value will be returned.

Also you have to **specify the place  holder** like:

```
string str = (String.Format("{0:0.0000}", coefficient));
```

Consider the following example:

```
String.Format("{0:0.0000}", 1.2345123123) //would return "1.2345"
String.Format("{0:0.0000}", "1.2345123123")//would return "1.2345123123" ignoring the format
```

Comment: Actually the OP isn't using `string.format` correctly.  There is no `{0}` in the format.

Comment: @juharr, just added it after your comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class PolynomialCoefficients<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> coefficients;

    public string ToString(string format)
    {
        const string separator = ":";
        return string.Join(separator, coefficients.Select(c => string.Format("{0:f4}", c)));
    }
}
```

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I have edited my answer, but nonetheless - I think using `string.Join` is far more readable than OPs solution. Matter of personal preferrence. I appreciate your comment, though.

Comment: I was actually referencing the derivation of `IEnumerable` to solve this, not string.Join (which I think is a good solution). Then I noticed the OP was already doing this, so I removed the comment :) The only thing missing from your answer is an explanation

Comment: It is *actually* a very good solution, considering OP is doing the same thing with removing last character from the generated string. +1 for `String.Join`

Answer (score 0):

You should constrain `T` to `IFormattable`:

```
public class PolynomialCoefficients<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    where T : IFormattable
```

With that you can use `coefficient.ToString("0.0000", null)` where `coefficient` is a `T`. You can also use:

```
polynomialString.AppendFormat("{0:0.0000}", coefficient)
```

with your `StringBuilder`. That will end up calling `coefficient.ToString("0.0000", null)` as well.